How to show annotations by click on the column in swiftUI Charts
When I try to display the annotation by using onTapGesture, it appears in the middle of the chart.
When I click on the column, it should show my annotation on top of the column, as you can see in the screenshot below. I've tried everything, but it is always presented in the middle of the chart. How can I do this?
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct FocusChartView: View {
    var colorStyleTask: Array<Color> = [Color(.black).opacity(0.7), Color(.white)]
    
    let focusStats: [FocusTime] = [
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 1, day: 1), focusCount: 1),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 2, day: 1), focusCount: 3),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 3, day: 1), focusCount: 7),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 4, day: 1), focusCount: 12),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 5, day: 1), focusCount: 5),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 6, day: 1), focusCount: 12),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 7, day: 1), focusCount: 1),]
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            taskCharts
        }
    }
    
    private var taskCharts: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.gray)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            Chart {
                let maxViews = focusStats.map { $0.focusCount }.max() ?? 1
                
                ForEach(focusStats) { viewMonth in
                    let viewCount = Double(viewMonth.focusCount)
                    let scaledHeight = (viewCount / Double(maxViews)) * 90
                    let relativeHeight = max(42.0, scaledHeight)
                    
                    BarMark(
                        x: .value("Month", viewMonth.date, unit: .month),
                        y: .value("Views", relativeHeight)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(
                        SwiftUI.LinearGradient(
                            gradient: SwiftUI.Gradient(colors: colorStyleTask),
                            startPoint: .bottom,
                            endPoint: .top
                        )
                    )
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
                    .annotation(position: .top) {
                        VStack {
                            Text(viewMonth.date.formattedToMonthAndYear())
                            Text(viewMonth.focusCount.toHoursAndMinutes())
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 8)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 12)
                        .background(Color(.white))
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.1), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 3)
                        .offset(y: -3)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 151)
            .chartXAxis {
                AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .month)) { _ in
                    AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.month(.abbreviated), centered: true)
                }
            }
            .chartYAxis {
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    FocusChartView()
}


struct FocusTime: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let date: Date
    let focusCount: Int
}

extension Int {
    func toHoursAndMinutes() -> String {
        let hours = self / 60
        let minutes = self % 60
        return "\(hours)h \(minutes)m"
    }
}

extension Date {
    static func from(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) -> Date {
        let components = DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: day)
        return Calendar.current.date(from: components)!
    }
    
    func formattedToMonthAndYear() -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM, yyyy"
        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}




To display your annotations on top of the chart bar when you tap/click on it,
try this approach using a var selectedItem and .chartGesture
as shown in the example code.
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
       FocusChartView()
   }
}

struct FocusChartView: View {
    var colorStyleTask = [Color(.black).opacity(0.7), Color(.white)]
    
    let focusStats: [FocusTime] = [
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 1, day: 1), focusCount: 1),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 2, day: 1), focusCount: 3),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 3, day: 1), focusCount: 7),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 4, day: 1), focusCount: 12),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 5, day: 1), focusCount: 5),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 6, day: 1), focusCount: 12),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 7, day: 1), focusCount: 1)]
    
    @State private var selectedItem: UUID?  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            taskCharts
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private var taskCharts: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.gray)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            Chart {
                let maxViews = focusStats.map { $0.focusCount }.max() ?? 1
                
                ForEach(focusStats) { viewMonth in
                    
                    let viewCount = Double(viewMonth.focusCount)
                    let scaledHeight = (viewCount / Double(maxViews)) * 90
                    let relativeHeight = max(42.0, scaledHeight)
                    
                    BarMark(
                        x: .value("Month", viewMonth.date, unit: .month),
                        y: .value("Views", relativeHeight)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(
                        SwiftUI.LinearGradient(
                            gradient: SwiftUI.Gradient(colors: colorStyleTask),
                            startPoint: .bottom,
                            endPoint: .top
                        )
                    )
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
                    .annotation(position: .top) {
                        if selectedItem == viewMonth.id {  // <--- here
                            VStack {
                                Text(viewMonth.date.formattedToMonthAndYear())
                                Text(viewMonth.focusCount.toHoursAndMinutes())
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                            }
                            .padding(.top, 8)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 12)
                            .background(Color(.white))
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.1), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 3)
                            .offset(y: -3)
                        }
                        else {
                            Text("").frame(height: 55) // <--- here, or adjust chart height
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 151)
            .chartXAxis {
                AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .month)) { _ in
                    AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.month(.abbreviated), centered: true)
                }
            }
            
            .chartGesture { proxy in  // <--- here
                SpatialTapGesture()
                    .onEnded { item in
                        if let target: (date: Date, temp: Double) = proxy.value(at: item.location, as: (Date, Double).self),
                            let chartData = closestChartData(to: target) {
                            selectedItem = chartData.id
                        }
                    }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func closestChartData(to target: (date: Date, temp: Double)) -> FocusTime? {
        var closestChartData: FocusTime?
        for datum in focusStats {
            if sameMonth(date: datum.date, tgt: target.date) {
                closestChartData = datum
                break
            }
        }
        return closestChartData
    }
    
    func sameMonth(date: Date, tgt: Date) -> Bool {
        let month = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: date, to: tgt)
        return month.month == 0 ? true : false
    }
   
}


For iOS 17 and later, chartXSelection provides the ability to select chart values with a tap or a drag. See WWDC talk "Explore pie charts and interactivity in Swift Charts" starting at 4:23 and sample code
The following is the chart updated using chartXSelection:


The following adds chart selection and gestures where rawSelectedDate is the date selected:
.chartXSelection(value: $rawSelectedDate)

Provides Y values:
.chartYScale(domain: 0...150)

Keeps Barmarks static while selecting and keeps annotations on the chart:
overflowResolution: .init(x: .fit(to: .chart) , y: .disabled)

Selects the FocusTime data for the selected date:


    var selectedData: FocusTime? {
        if let rawSelectedDate {
            return focusStats.first(where: {
                $0.date.get(.month) == rawSelectedDate.get(.month) &&
                $0.date.get(.year) == rawSelectedDate.get(.year)
            })
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

Modified code:
struct FocusChartView: View {
    
    @State var rawSelectedDate: Date? = nil
    
    var selectedData: FocusTime? {
        if let rawSelectedDate {
            return focusStats.first(where: {
                $0.date.get(.month) == rawSelectedDate.get(.month) &&
                $0.date.get(.year) == rawSelectedDate.get(.year)
            })
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    var colorStyleTask: Array<Color> = [Color(.black).opacity(0.7), Color(.white)]
    
    let focusStats: [FocusTime] = [
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 1, day: 1), focusCount: 1),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 2, day: 1), focusCount: 3),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 3, day: 1), focusCount: 7),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 4, day: 1), focusCount: 12),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 5, day: 1), focusCount: 5),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 6, day: 1), focusCount: 12),
        .init(date: Date.from(year: 2024, month: 7, day: 1), focusCount: 1),]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            taskCharts
        }
    }
    
    private var taskCharts: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.gray)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            Chart {
                let maxViews = focusStats.map { $0.focusCount }.max() ?? 1
                
                ForEach(focusStats) { viewMonth in
                    let viewCount = Double(viewMonth.focusCount)
                    let scaledHeight = (viewCount / Double(maxViews)) * 90
                    let relativeHeight = max(42.0, scaledHeight)
                    
                    BarMark(
                        x: .value("Month", viewMonth.date, unit: .month),
                        y: .value("Views", relativeHeight)
                    )
                    .foregroundStyle(
                        SwiftUI.LinearGradient(
                            gradient: SwiftUI.Gradient(colors: colorStyleTask),
                            startPoint: .bottom,
                            endPoint: .top
                        )
                    )
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
                    let data = selectedData
                    if let data {
                        RuleMark (
                            x: .value("Selected", data.date, unit: .month)
                        )
                        .foregroundStyle(Color.secondary)
                        .offset(yStart: -10)
                        .annotation (
                            position: .top, spacing: 0,
                            overflowResolution: .init(x: .fit(to: .chart) , y: .disabled)
                        ) {
                            VStack {
                                Text(data.date.formattedToMonthAndYear())
                                Text(data.focusCount.toHoursAndMinutes())
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                            }
                            .padding([.top, .bottom], 8)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 12)
                            .background(Color(.systemBackground) )
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.1), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 3)
                            .offset(y: -3)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .chartXSelection(value: $rawSelectedDate) // chart gestures
            .frame(height: 151)
            .chartXAxis {
                AxisMarks(values: .stride(by: .month)) { _ in
                    AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.month(.abbreviated), centered: true)
                }
            }
            .chartYScale(domain: 0...150) // add y values to chart
        }
    }
}


// Addition to the Date extension
extension Date {
    func get(_ component: Calendar.Component, calendar: Calendar = Calendar.current) -> Int {
        return calendar.component(component, from: self)
    }
}

